# Laravel 5.4 route name not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

In my routes on web.php I have the following line

```
Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@create')->name('dashboard');
```

In my DashboardController.php I have a `create` function with the following line like I saw on a **Laracast tutorial** but it's not working.

```
return redirect()->dashboard();
```

I get the following error

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::dashboard()
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I think you shoud do `redirect()->to('dashboard');`

Answer (score 5):

You should use

```
return redirect()->route('dashboard');
```

this is the way to do it.

visit [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes) for more info

Answer (score 0):

`return redirect()->dashboard();` calls a method named as `dashboard` inside your controller and that's what error is saying

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError
>
> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::dashboard()

You need to call named routes like this

```
return redirect()->route('dashboard');
```

For deep insight always trust [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
return redirect()->dashboard();
```

Try:

```
return redirect()->route('your-route-name');
```